# Why are global functions considered "wrong" in Angular 1.3

Tags: angularjs

Traditionally I have managed my Angular code like this

```
//File 1
angular.module('name',[])
//File 2
function TestController(){

}
TestController.prototype.// inherited stuff
angular.module('name').controller('testController',TestController);
```

This worked great and allowed me to partition my files easily. Now I try to upgrade to 1.3 and get the infamous...

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'TestController' is not a function, got undefined
```

Of course this is due to [this change](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3f2232b5a181512fac23775b1df4a6ebda67d018) which claims a desire to clean up the way people write code. What about this pattern is more complex? Is there a way to maintain this pattern without changing the global settings?

Comment: I know I threw this together to try to get across a point. This is actually valid (I am pretty sure) because of angular.module('name').controller('testController',TestController); but you are right the case in the error message may be wrong.

Comment: Using your own global variables and functions is a code design flaw that is prone to error.

Comment: @Brett You were right this was just one big misunderstanding and a typo. Sorry about shrugging it off checking if it works once that is fixed. I think it is only an issue with truely global controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually a [comment on the page you linked](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3f2232b5a181512fac23775b1df4a6ebda67d018#commitcomment-8231175) to that had a fairly solid explanation.

> Global controllers refer to your controllers being defined as function
>   on the window object. This means that they are openly available to
>   conflict with any other bit of JavaScript that happens to define a
>   function with the same name. Admittedly, if you post-fix your
>   controllers with ...Controller then this could well not happen but
>   there is always the chance, especially if you were to use a number of
>   3rd party libraries. It is much safer to put these controller
>   functions inside the safety of a module. You then have more control
>   over when and where this module gets loaded. Unfortunately controller
>   names are global across an individual Angular app and so you still
>   have the potential for conflict but at least you can't clash with
>   completely different code in the JavaScript global namespace.

So the idea is that global controller functions could conflict with any other global function in any javascript you use. So to eliminate the chance of a conflict with your own code or a third-party script, not using global controllers makes your code safer and more consistent.

As mentioned in the comments by @Brett, you can use IIFE around your prototyping. [Here is an update of your plunk that uses that](http://plnkr.co/edit/abakP6fmnGk2DLhwisgh?p=preview). The main change just looks like this.

```
(function() {
  TestController.prototype.name = 'World'
})();
```

Comment: But doesn't this also mean I can't use prototyping? That is a huge compromise IMHO!

Comment: @Jackie Wrap it in an IIFE and it's not global.

Comment: Not familiar do you have a link or an example? I just added a plunker to give an idea how I handle things typically.

Comment: @Jackie Check out my update and see if that helps clarify things.

Comment: Is this type of idea what you are referring to http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2521-using-base-controllers-in-angularjs-an-experiment.htm? If so I think I get it but that looks far uglier. am I really gaining anything from it as opposed to globals?

Comment: @Jackie I'm not entirely sure what he is trying to do in that example. Personally, after the update to 1.3, I just use anonymous functions in the controller definitions. Whether it is more or less readable is debatable but I feel a lot better about the structure of the code after the change than what I had before. As mentioned, the biggest gain in not using globals is the safety of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

What comes to my mind is 2 things:

1) in that way functions wont be kept in memory more than they should.

2) if you minify your code, minifyer will have to generate new names for all global objects, which is sfine when you have small project, but will be a problem when it's not.

Also it should prevent tests to modify unnecessary data.

Comment: The minification argument I think is a poor one. I run NGAnnotate before I run my minification and everything works fine. Maybe if you really don't understand how DI minification works than this might be an issue. Also I believe the cost of keeping the function in memory is rather low right? Keeping code with a bunch of inline functions clean seems like a bigger problem.