# AngularJS controller does not work, why? (simple controller example)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just saw a video of introduction to AngularJS and use the following example

**The html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainContrl">

  <h2>{{message}}</h2>

 <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/test.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

**The js:**

```
 var MainContrl = function($scope){
   $scope.message = "Hello friend";
 };
```

In the example I've seen this structure works, but when I test it does not work.
The console gives me this error:

```
 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/areq?p0=MainContrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

Can be used in this way the controller?
Or is it a bad practice

**Example in Plunker:**
[Code example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZylGhUtFcZ89wBKQqXIe?p=preview)

Comment: You need to create the module and then hook the controller to it but calling `module.controller('MainContrl', MainContrl)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are global functions considered "wrong" in Angular 1.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232551/why-are-global-functions-considered-wrong-in-angular-1-3)

Comment: The error line you're showing is literally giving a link to a page describing that it's failing to find a hooked 'MainControl' function, as @emodendroket describes. This may seem a bit obvious, but it's a feature I certainly like about AngularJS as a framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it's a bad practice

You better use:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainContrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
     // any code here
]);
```

And use this in HTML:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <body ng-controller="MainContrl">
         // any code here
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to define your angular App first :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainContrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Hello friend";
});
```

here is a [working example on Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/c2DNJpEXJWGjdN7nGDCO?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to have a main app.

In **myapp.js**

```
var yourApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

In **mainController.js** (it should not be called test.js)

```
yourApp.controller('MainController',['$scope',function($scope){

    $scope.message = "Hello world";

}]);
```

In your **index.html**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

   <body ng-controller="MainController">
      {{message}}
   </body>'
 <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/myapp.js"></script>
 <script src="js/mainController.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Your script.js to

```
var app=angular.module('myapp',[]);

app.controller('MainContrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.message = "Hello friend";
}]);
```

and in html page put ng-app in body tag and remove ng-app from html

```
 <body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainContrl">
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare your app in your html:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Second define your app in your js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Then definewhatever controller in whatever js file (best practice sugests that every controller has its own file):

```
var MainContrl = function($scope){
   $scope.message = "Hello friend";
 };
```

Then declare your controller and variables in your html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainContrl">
  <h2>{{message}}</h2>
 </body>
```

Don't forget to bind your controller with your app:

```
app.controller('MainContrl',MainContrl);
```

I also can see that you're using bower, so I suggest you read this:
http://www.sitepoint.com/kickstart-your-angularjs-development-with-yeoman-grunt-and-bower/

Comment: You're right I forgot something: `app.controller('MainContrl',MainContrl);` I will edit the answer, thank you http://plnkr.co/edit/QvbbjeYubpXYa3ZtXQsN?p=preview