# Inclusion of Angular into HTML is being tricky

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to extend my knowledge of JS by learning angular or at the very least get an understanding of angular. I am trying to go through [this tutorial](https://www.thinkful.com/learn/angularjs-tutorial-build-a-gmail-clone/#Setup-Scopes-and-Directives) but I can not get my downloaded version of angular to load.

I have tried replacing my copy of of the js file with the one included on the [GitHub for the tutorial](https://github.com/Thinkful/guide-intro-to-angular/tree/master/app/02-sample-controller) and that works but when I try and link to my local copy it breaks.

This code doesn't work but as soon as the angular file is replaced with one from the repo it works. The two copies of angular are in the same lib folder and I have double checked the names. I have also tried using Google's CDN but that doesn't work either.

Any thoughts on why angular would be acting up this way?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <title>Sample AngularJS Controller</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <input type="text" ng-model="title">
    </div>

    <script src="lib/jquery-v1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular.js"></script> <!--Fresh Download-->

    <!--If I replace the angular.js link with this it works.-->
    <!--<script src="lib/angular-v1.2.22.js"></script>-->

    <script>
      function TestCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.title = "Example title! (Change or delete me)";
    };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are both versions of Angular the same? Could be that the version from the tutorial is older and the code used in the tutorial is no longer supported by the current version. Angular 1.2.x is the legacy version and is pretty outdated(the version from the tutorial was released Aug 12, 2014). Do you get any errors in your developer console?

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions or errors?

Comment: angular.js:13708 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'TestCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are global functions considered "wrong" in Angular 1.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232551/why-are-global-functions-considered-wrong-in-angular-1-3)

Comment: Based on the error message, angular itself *is* loading, but your code is incompatible with the current version of Angular (I wouldn't call the question an exact duplicate, but @MatthewGreen's link above looks likely). v1.2 was a long time ago, you may want to find a less out-of-date tutorial to learn from.

Comment: Sounds like a plan to me thanks. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: I used egghead.io when I was first learning, but honestly that was a long time ago too, looks like the good stuff is behind a paywall now.  Sorry, wish I had something better for you